# How can I access the name of the selector that's attached to a UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, unit-testing

I have a gesture recognizer attached to a view and I'd like to be able to unit test which method it calls when the tap occurs.  My gesture recognizer is created like so...

```
- (void)setupMyView {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myViewTapped)];
    self.myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.myView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

How can I access the name of the selector (myViewTapped) that is called when the tap occurs?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither `UIGestureRecognizer` nor `UITapGestureRecognizer` exposes this information.

`UIControl`, for example, exposes `allTargets` and `allControlEvents`, which is basically what you are looking for, but it is unfortunately unavailable for `UIGestureRecognizer`

As a result, I do not believe what you want is possible without using private methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use this inside the method `myViewTapped`,

```
NSLog(@"method name: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd))
```

This one also can print the method name,

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

[Source:](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)